# One scene, but multiple viewports with their own camera (three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have a scene that I'd like to reuse, rendering the scene in two divs with a different camera angle for each div.

[This link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/189) says a scene cannot be shared between multiple renderers, and suggests using multiple viewports with a single renderer. How can I assign multiple cameras to a renderer, and then get the DOM element that each is displayed in?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You want to do it exactly as in this three.js example:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_views.html

This uses multiple viewports, not multiple divs. It really is the best way.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to update this answer for 2018, as this is one of the top Google hits when looking for user examples.

This was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/6723). With several [examples](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_multiple_canvases_circle.html) added.

Passing an existing scene to another renderer instance works as you would expect now.